# Update/Edit entity with relations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working in MVC and creating som CRUD operations. I am not a pro, som im having trouble doing the Update/edit of an entity, when the entity have a relation, that i also want to update. Here is a short description of the tables:

I have a model called "User" with follwing properties (userId and so on....)
I have a model called "Address" with following properties (addressId, street, zipcode, city)

I have a model called "Home" with following properties (StreetNumber, floor, side, and two navigation properties"userid" and "addressId").

Now.. i have a viewModel with the properties from Address and Home.. And i want to update Both using this viewModel. Im not having probilem showing all the data in my view. But i cannot update both entities at the same time?

Can anyone give an example on how to do this? 
Can i update the address model going through the home model?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Share your code and please review [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would've been easier if you had posted some of your code, but I'll assume what you have.

First, I'd update your viewmodel and include `id` of the user:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
  public Guid Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string Surname {get;set;}
  public string City {get;set;}
  public string Address {get;set;}
}
```

Then you just have to map the properties from the ViewModel to the properties of the model. Since you mentioned that you have some navigation properties it shouldn't be hard to find the address of the user you want to update.

```
  public void Update(UserViewModel userVM)
  {
      var user = db.Users.Find(userVM.Id);
      if(user != null)
      {
        user.Name = userVM.Name;
        user.Surname = userVM.Surname;

        var address = user.Address;
        address.City = userVM.City;
        address.Address = userVM.Address;

        db.SaveChanges();
      }
    }
```

I think you should get the idea now.

In case you don't have navigation properties just include the `id` of the address to your viewmodel so you can find it the same way as I did for the user.